# Why does firefox keep saying having trouble getting your pages after upgrading to 18.04?

Tags: firefox

After upgrading to 18.04 every time I start Ubuntu and the fire up Firefox I get a "Sorry. We’re having trouble getting your pages back."

How to I fix this?

Comment: You could try to delete OR backup your settings (it also includes history), Close Firefox first, open your file manger such as nautilus click on home directory press Ctrl+H to view hidden folders there is a folder named: .mozilla (it begins with a dot) backup this folder somewhere safe to place it back later if you wish, now delete it from home directory and try to execute Firefox and see if is working.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion, sound like that would work but its a bit too drastic for me.  I had a play with the setting and found I could fix it.  See below.

Comment: It may be your addon settings or some other settings the only way to find it out is to use the default settings like i suggested previously but it's up to you, but i will suggest you to try chromium is the leader of browsers on GNU/Linux trust me.

Comment: No need for chromium, all is working well now thanks.  I use to play with computers all the time but found it was sucking to much of my life away.  So now days I go for the simplest quickest solution to get my computer to work and then enjoy my life.  Just off to play my guitar!  Couldn't do that if I was using Windows!

Answer (score 0):

OK I had a play with firefox settings.  First off I turned restore session ON.  A bit odd it was trying to restore sessions when it was turned OFF?  Then I turned it back OFF.  This made things a lot better but I then noticed Easy Image Blocker addon was playing up.  It was blocking images at start up even when I had set it t show images.  So I uninstalled this addon and replaced it with ImageBlocker.  All seems well now!

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, the solution:

(1) `about:config` in the address bar and press Enter.
Click the button promising to be careful.

(2) In the search box above the list, type `resume_from_crash`

(3) Double-click the `browser.sessionstore.resume_from_crash` to switch it from true to **false**.